# Updating UI from another class

Tags: objective-c, encapsulation

I have two classes (Class A & Class B). Class B downloads and processes some data while class A shows a progressView.

I need the progressView in Class A to update when called by the Class B.

Currently I have the following in Class B.m:

```
ClassA* classA= [[ClassA alloc] init];

[classA didStartLoadMethod];
```

and inside Class A.h:

```
- (void)didStartLoadMethod;
```

Inside ClassA.m

```
- (void)didStartLoadMethod;
{
    _progressView.progress = 0;
}
```

But the progress view will not update unless **didStartLoadMethod** is called from class A.

Are the any other ways of doing it? Am I doing it wrong?

Any help would me much appreciated and/or any other solutions. 
Thanks

Comment: "progress view will not update unless didStartLoadMethod is called from class A" is untrue.  More than likely, class B's pointer to class A is invalid.  Google "iOS delegate pattern", and in particular, NSURLConnectionDelegate.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: The key here is your statement, "I have two classes (Class A & Class B)" -- you already have these two controllers, so you shouldn't be creating a new instance of ClassA with alloc init. You need to get a pointer to the instance you already have. How you do this depends on your app structure.

Comment: How do i do that? @rdelmar

Comment: I can't tell you without more information. That's why I said it depends on your app structure. How are those two controllers created? How do you go from one to the other?

Comment: The **Class A** is a UIView with a **ContainerView** inside. The **ContainerView** is linked to **Class B** @rdelmar

Comment: Do you really mean Class A is a view, not a view controller?

Comment: Try not having views affect the state of their fellow views.  Fundamentally, a view is a ball of state that knows how to draw itself, not a dictator.  Move the logic affecting presentation into a controller.

Comment: **Class A** is a **ViewController** sorry. @rdelmar

Comment: I would put the **ProgressView** inside **Class B** but **Class B** is a **UITableViewController** therefor I can not put it in a location I want. @CodaFi

Comment: I've been down this road before and seen how it ends... what you really want is a class C that has NO ui or views or presentation and JUST knows how to download and process some data. It in turn has a delegate that it calls with status updates, and the delegate decides how to display progress on its views. You'll be happy in the long run if you separate things in this way.

Comment: @RobP I would still have the problem of not being able to change the **progressView** progress. Wouldn't I?

Comment: depending whether you want things tightly or loosely coupled, you do one of these patterns a) view with progress sets itself as the delegate of the downloader class b) view with progress uses a "registerObserver" style interface to get updates from downloader class, where it keeps a list of observers as opposed to just a single delegate, c) downloader class posts notifications, class that shows progress registers to receive them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of playing around I just settled for a `NSNotification`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a parent-child relationship between your two controllers, you can access the ClassA controller from the ClassB controller with self.parentViewController (this code is in Class B).

```
ClassA* classA= (ClassA *)self.parentViewController;

[classA didStartLoadMethod];
```

Comment: It didn't run the method in **Class A**

Comment: @JohannBurgess try logging classA (after that first line) and see what it gives.

Comment: I loged **classA** as you said and received **null**

Comment: @JohannBurgess, I don't know how that could be if you have the hierarchy of controllers that you say you have. If you could post an image of your storyboard somewhere that I could see, I might be able to say why this isn't working.